# Need help sending HTTP post to login on twitter

Tags: java, javascript, http, twitter, jsoup

I am desperately trying to send an HTTP post to authenticate to twitter via JAVA but I keep getting HTTP 400 response code.

this is the HTML Code for the form that I want to use:

Sign in    Remember me Â· Forgot password?     
  New to Twitter?

I am using JSOUP to try to access the class "signin" from the form at the top. I want to do that because I want to then use this code:

```
Element loginform = doc.getElementByClass("signin");
Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");


List<NameValuePair> paramList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
    String key = inputElement.attr("name");
    String value = inputElement.attr("value");
    if (key.equals("session[username_or_email]"))
        value = username;
    else if (key.equals("session[password]"))
        value = password;

    paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));

}
```

This code will not work because the "loginform" class must be "getElemenById" instead of "getElementByClass", but the thing is, in the form, the "signin" is a class.

So my question is how do i get inputElements from a class instead of an id? I need this so that I can extract the parameters to send a valid HTTP POST to twitter so that I can authenticate an account.

ALL help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The power in JSoup is utilizing CSS selectors to handle parsing HTML.   Take a look at the examples on jsoup.org.

For your specific example, try:

```
doc.select("input.signin")
```

Where the tag.class or tag#id  or combine with other selectors as shown in the documentation.